# Comparing 2 Arrays

Tags: arrays, compare

I have 2 arrays a & b with same length n.

I want to compare every element of a with every element of b. The 2 arrays are not sorted. How can I achieve my goal with an algorithm that has a complexity less that O(n^2)? Like O(n) or O(nlogn)?

The ultimate goal is to find a pair of numbers from these arrays such that their difference is the length of the arrays.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? If you are only going to compare everything of, with everything of b, you will need O(n^2). My opinion is that the whole idea of the reduction in complexity comes into picture, coz you dont have to do all the operations.

Comment: yes I want to compare everything of a with everything of b but i want an algorithm does it in less than O(n^2) time..

Comment: But why do you need to compare the arrays? What is the purpose of these comparisons? If you literally are just comparing the elements for the sake of comparing them it is impossible to do so in less then `O(n^2)` time. But if you have some purpose for comparing every element, such as finding the intersection of the two arrays or whether they have the same element, then that totally changes your question.

Comment: Sort 2nd array,
Then iterate through 1st array and binary search each element in 2nd array.

Comment: Yes I do have a purpose. I want to find such a pair of numbers in(numbers being from each array) so that the difference between those numbers is length of the arrays. If such a pair exists then the function will return true.

Comment: How did your sort + binary search method work out? It looks like it should have worked in `O(nlog(n))` time.

Comment: Just to understand your question correctly, can you provide an example, like input and output

Comment: According to my understanding this should be the Input, A:- 2,4,6,7  and B:- 8,10,12,22 so your answer would be yes because pair(4,8) or pair (6,10) have difference 4 which is the length of the array, Am I right ?

Comment: A : [5, 3, 2, 12, 8]
B: [2, 9, 10, 4, 6]

Algorithm will search for a pair of numbers 1 number from each array such that their difference is the length of the arrays.

In this case length is 5. so array will return the pair 5,10.

5 from A and 10 from B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want, and is as efficient as your sorting algorithm:

1. Create temporary arrays `a1,a2` which contain the elements of `a` minus and plus the array length `n`, respectively.
2. Concatenate `a1` and `a2` and sort the result, to obtain `a'`.
3. Sort `b` to obtain `b'`.
4. Initiate counters `i=0, j=0`
5. While `a'[i]!=b'[j]`:

   1. While `i<n and a'[i]<b'[j]`: `i++`
   2. If `i==n`: Return "not found!"
   3. While `j<n and b'[j]<a'[i]`: `j++`
   4. If `j==n`: Return "not found!"
6. Return  "found!"

Comment: You sir are awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if sizes of both arrays are same then initiate a loop and iterate through the indexes of both arrays and compare them using comparison operators.

Comment: but that will only compare the elements of the same indices. I want to compare all the elements of bot arrays.

Comment: then u can have nested loop 1st loop iterates 1st array nested loop iterates second array. then for each of the nth element of the 1st array it'll compare all the elements of the second array through nested loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use in merge sort O(nlogn) and then comparing the arrays from the end 
2O(nlogn) +O(n)